# jqPlot not showing x-axis label or formatting axis

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am generating a line graph with two lines on it using the function below.  My problem is that it is not showing the x-axis label (I've tried it both as a variable and hard coded).  It is also not formatting the x-axis values per the tickOptions.  I have a seperate plot that is using date values on the x-axis instead of regular numerical and it has no issues.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
function toolProbPlot(probDivTitle,probValues,probPlotTitle,probX,legendLabel) {
    return plot = $.jqplot(probDivTitle,probValues, {
        title: probPlotTitle,
        seriesColors:[noColor,yesColor],
        legend: {
            show: true,
            location:  legendLocation,
            placement: legendPlacement,
            labels: legendLabel
        },
        axis: {
            xaxis: {
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                showLabel: true,
                label: probX,
                tickOptions: {formatString: '%.4f'}
            },
            yaxis: {
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo: `axis: {` should be `axes: {`

Also make sure to have included all the required .js plugins

Comment: Well, that will make you feel silly.  Thanks for pointing out the obvious!